# dim of skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the dimension of

- a) the skew-symmetric matrices
- b) the matrices for which each row has sum zero.

I don't understand the book's short solution "try to express the basis in terms of elementary matrices $E_{ij}$".

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ a matrix  then since $(E_{ij})$ is the canonical basis of $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ we have
$$A=\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}a_{ij}E_{ij}$$
now since $A$ is skew-symmetric then
$$A^T=-A$$
hence
$$a_{ij}=-a_{ji}\quad;\quad a_{ii}=0$$
so
$$A=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_{ij}(E_{ij}-E_{ji})$$
hence $(E_{ij}-E_{ji})_{1\le i<j\le n}$ is basis of the linear space of skew-symmetric matrices $\mathcal{AS}_n(\mathbb R)$ hence
$$\dim \mathcal{AS}_n(\mathbb R)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$